# Develop personal iOS app without submitting to app store

Tags: ios

I would like to develop an iOS app entirely for my own personal use without ever submitting it to the app store. I have searched this site and found that I would need to pay Apple $99 and join the developer program. There was one post which suggested that I would be removed from the program by Apple if I never used the app store. Is this correct?

Thanks.

ps. I have no wish to jailbreak any of my iOS devices

Comment: As far as I know, as long as you keep paying the $99 every year you are fine.

Comment: "There was one post which suggested that I would be removed from the program by Apple if I never used the app store. Is this correct?" No, that sounds like FUD. You think Apple wants to turn down your $99/year? :)

Comment: Thanks. It sounded like FUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will not discontinue your account if you never submit to the app store. It is important to realize though, that your certificates on device will expire and you will have to renew them... so it's not $99.

It's $99/yr. You will need to keep renewing if you want to keep your app on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you know someone who is a developer, you could pay them to do the paid for stuff, this way you could pay much less and still develop it yourself. Then they could do an adhoc distribution and avoid the App Store.

Comment: Thanks. The only developer I know is the ex-boyfriend of my youngest step-daughter. I am already on his list, but none of my devices are. It would be a little awkward to pursue this with him...

Comment: Truthfully, look on craigslist or something like that, I'll bet you could find someone who would do this for like 10 bucks, it doesn't take them much time - as long as you are the one coding the app - tops this would be like 30 minutes of work to create the provisioning profile, create the certs, archive the app for delivery, and distribute through adhoc. Though, if it is only on the one device, you could just build and leave the app in dev mode on your device, then they only need the profile and cert, they download that and send it to you for 10 bucks a year or something. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks again, Doug. Actually, I just paid Apple and joined the program. Perhaps is it partial payment for the years of using their stuff for free -- I did Cocoa development (writing little OpenGL physics demos) in OS X since the public beta in 2000.

Comment: Truthfully, that's the way I would go, but I saw another option that hadn't been posted. As a paying dev you have more access and can make something else to possibly make some money.